# using module leaflet-tilelayer-wmts in a angular-cli

Tags: leaflet, wmts

I am trying to use the module leaflet-tilelayer-wmts to have wmts support in leaflet .  "leaflet-tilelayer-wmts" is available in npm.
The module is in a javasccript and does not contain the setting for a module .

I already inlude it in my package.json, successfulley, it download in mu node_module directory..

But I still cannot import it  using the command :

```
import * as Wmts from '../node_modules/leaflet-tilelayer-wmts/src/leaflet-tilelayer-wmts';
```

I also copy the javascript files in directory  assets   and then use :

```
import * as wmts  from 'assets/LeafletWMTS';
```

But from that I don`t known how to use it since

```
 L.tileLayer.wmts
```

give an error when trying to create the tileLayer :   WMTS property does not exist on type  "typeof tilelayer"

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare this module for using it with TypeScript. You can do this in typings.d.ts file in 'src' folder with next code:

```
declare namespace L {
  namespace TileLayer {
    class WMTS extends TileLayer {
      constructor(baseUrl: string, options: any);
      setParams(params: any, noRedraw?: boolean): this;

      wmtsParams: any;
      options: any;
    }
  }

  namespace tileLayer {
    function wmts(baseUrl: string, options?: any): TileLayer.WMTS;
  }
}
```

Note, if you're running ng build with --watch flag you need to restart it.
Also you can create more infomative declaration for options parameters instead of using any.

UPD: You also need to simplify your import:

```
import '../node_modules/leaflet-tilelayer-wmts/src/leaflet-tilelayer-wmts';
```

Comment: the library I am using is  :  [leaflet.TileLayer.WMTS](https://github.com/mylen/leaflet.TileLayer.WMTS).  So you said I need to declare a module  but how can I link the newly created module  to the js code of the library ?  .  Thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: I put the d.ts file in the same src directory where that  d.ts  is being called but  I got an error    "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../node_modules/leaflet-tilelayer-wmts/src/leaflet-tilelayer-wmts'".  I put the import instruction as you indicated.   And the javascript file is in the directory   "../node_modules/leaflet-tilelayer-wmts/src/leaflet-tilelayer-wmts'"